# Get the billing info onload in woocommerce before process payment

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Can we use jquery to get the billing address info in woocommerce before process payment. Using last focused element can we get the entried billing address firstname,lastname,etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an example to get the customer billing information in jQuery (before processing payment):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_js_script' );
function custom_checkout_js_script() {
    // Targeting cart and checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) :

    $billing_first_name = WC()->customer->get_billing_first_name();
    $billing_last_name  = WC()->customer->get_billing_last_name();

    $billing_address_1  = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_1();
    $billing_address_2  = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_2();
    $billing_postcode   = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();
    $billing_city       = WC()->customer->get_billing_city();
    $billing_state      = WC()->customer->get_billing_state();
    $billing_country    = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var billing_first_name = '<?php echo $billing_first_name; ?>',
            billing_last_name  = '<?php echo $billing_last_name; ?>',
            billing_address_1  = '<?php echo $billing_address_1; ?>',
            billing_address_2  = '<?php echo $billing_address_2; ?>',
            billing_postcode   = '<?php echo $billing_postcode; ?>',
            billing_city       = '<?php echo $billing_city; ?>',
            billing_state      = '<?php echo $billing_state; ?>',
            billing_country    = '<?php echo $billing_country; ?>';
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.